# AngularJS - How to Send Common URL Parameters on All Request?

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor, url-parameters

I want to send the same url param on all requests either it's get or post request, like this:

```
?region=us&toolName=abc
```

Is it possible by using AngularJS interceptor? Or is there other better way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See also: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Answer (score 0):

Using an httpInterceptor would be best then you can check if other params already exist and extend them...or only use the ones shown

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS $http method lets you specify your HTTP request verb as well as such parameters via the `config` object which can contain a `params` object, which can be something like `{ region: "us", toolName: "abc" }` which in turn becomes a query string. Example use:

```
$http({ url: "test.aspx", method: "GET", params: { region: "us", toolName: "abc" } }).then(
function(response){
     alert("success!");
}, function(response){
    alert("failure.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service to set default params request:

```
'use strict';

var ParamsService = function() {

  return {
    set: function (params) {
      var defaultParams = {
        region: 'us',
        toolName: 'abc'
      };

      // Use any function to extend objects (currently, I'm using lodash)
      return _.extend(defaultParams, params);
    }
  };
};

ParamsService.$inject = [

];
```

Request:

```
$http({ 
  url: 'url.json', 
  method: 'GET', 
  params: ParamsService.set({otherProperty: otherValue}) 
})
.then(
  function (data) {

  },

  function (error) {

  }
);
```

It not good solution, but can help your case :)

Answer (score 0):

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['key'] = 'value'